# C++ - Передача указателя на двумерный массив

Tags: массивы, указатели, c++

Есть метод с сигнатурой:

```
void AdjMatrix::setMatrix(int ** matrix)
```

И есть массив:

```
 int t[3][3] = {{1,0,0}, {0,1,0}, {0,0,1}};
```

Как передать методу указатель на данный массив?

Comment: Вы сами писали этот метод setMatrix?

Comment: Да, сам писал. Если это неправильный принцип работы с двумерными массивами, подскажите какой правильный.

Comment: @DarkGenius, в принципе можете попробовать

       setMatrix((int **)&t[0][0]);

Но, скорее всего это не то, что ожидает `setMatrix()`.

Очень похоже, что метод работает с "массивом" вида

     int *x[N];

который строится  таким образом

     for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       x[i] = new int [M];

Откуда `setMatrix()` берет размерность матрицы -- я не знаю (скорее всего это переменные класса, который Вы в вопросе опустили).

--

Пардон, пока писал и отвлекся, появилась дополнительная информация, что автор сам это все пишет и вопрос-то про другое...

Comment: @avp, наследовать класс не собираюсь, но мне будут нужны функции, вычисляющие инварианты графа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD:

```
void AdjMatrix::setMatrix(int** matrix, int n, int m)
{    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << (int)matrix[i*m+j] << "    ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

AdjMatrix::setMatrix((int**)t, 3, 3)
```

Comment: и скорее всего получите сообщение об ошибке компиляции

    error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[3]’ to ‘int**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void xxx(int**, int, int)’

Comment: ну да :) исправил

Comment: Добавил тестовую реализации метода

Comment: на будущее - в с++ нет методов.

Comment: @KoVadim, чего?

Comment: В с++ есть функции-члены. А методов - нет. Да, по факту - это одно и тоже, просто в с++ принято так их называть. Читайте стандарт.

Comment: Еще вопрос по реализации функции setMatrix. В ней можно копировать содержимое массива, переданное по указателю, либо просто присваивать полю класса переданный указатель. Сначала я выбрал второй вариант, но возникла проблема: в деструкторе удаляется объект по указателю, и если для этого объекта память выделялась в конструкторе (setMatrix не вызывался), все работает. Но если вызвать setMatrix, передав адрес статичного массива, возникает ошибка при вызове деструктора класса. Как сделать так, чтобы память освобождалась только если это действительно нужно?

Comment: Создать свое поле, хранящее массив матрикс, а в сетМатрикс() поэлементно скопировать переданный массив

Comment: Поэлеметно копировать это же медленно.

Comment: Но в вашем случае код вообще не рабочий, так что поэлементно копировать это не такое уже и зло :) Почитайте где-нибудь про работу с двумерными массивами и массивами указателей на массивы, так как приведенная выше мною ф-я просто костыль и к реальному кодингу никакого отношения не имеет, она может показаться работоспособной, но это только иллюзия

Comment: Хотите научиться работать с двумерными массивами - учите матчасть! Да и в гугле множество инфы по этому вопросу. На хэшкоде тоже не раз обсуждалось, например, http://hashcode.ru/questions/191722#19174

Comment: @DarkGenius, если хотите обстоятельного ответа, то опишите в вопросе свою задачу в целом, а не ее отдельный фрагмент, с которым у Вас возникли проблемы.

Comment: Да задача, связанная с графами. Реализую класс для матрицы смежности.
Отказался от использования "указателя на указатель", использую обычный одномерный массив и указатель на него.

Comment: На Питоне все это делается очень быстро, но мне захотелось попрактиковаться в C++)

Comment: @DarkGenius, а зачем Вам *класс*? Вы собираетесь наследоваться от него?

М.б. достаточно обычной структуры? А эффект инкапсуляции функций достигается тривиальной раздельной компиляцией.

IMHO чем проще написана (спроектирована) программа -- тем лучше.